# Postfix relay - Remove all traces of main node domain

Tags: postfix

I am using `mydomain.com` as the central server and `myrelay.com` as one of my SMTP relays.

I currently have the following set to convert the headers.

/etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/^Received:/ IGNORE
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@www.mydomain.com>/   REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@www.myrelay.com>
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

How would I go about checking on the relay for anything else to do with `mydomain.com`such as the subject or email message content (which may contain hyperlinks linking to `mydomain.com`)and then converting it to `myrelay.com`. I want there to be zero possible trace of `mydomain.com` anywhere in the full email headers.

Comment: I would recommend you to write a custom milter where you have lot of flexibility to do whatever you want to do. Take a look at [pymilter](http://pythonhosted.org/pymilter/)